# Parsing script that contains logic to execute

Tags: java, antlr4

I recently started to look at ANTLRv4 to give ability to users of my application to provide their custom logic for a specific domain.

I found in many places that embedding logic inside the grammar is a bad practice. Therefore, it seems the recommended approach is to walk through the tree generated by ANTLR and to produce some sort of object to represent script execution.

Does that mean I need to handle expression evaluation, method invocation, variable handling, etc...? Or is there a better approach for such use case?

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR 4 is a parser with a few utilities for obtaining information about the parse trees it creates. If you want to include expressions, methods, and/or variables in your language, then you will need to implement your own behavior for each of these regardless of where the code is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you know any sample project I can start with?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache The ANTLR4 book contains a sample C-like language which is parsed and processed. Tbis could serve as a starting point.